# Hibernate 4 javax/transaction/SystemException error

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to get Hibernate 4.3 to work with my MySQL database. I am already able to use the Hibernate Code Generation tool in Eclipse and I am also able to connect to the database using the Hibernate Configurations tool.

However when I try to run code in my Main class that queries the database I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2248)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:184)
at be.comp.permanenties.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
at be.comp.dao.balie.ZitdagenDAOMySQL.findByMaCode(ZitdagenDAOMySQL.java:31)
at be.comp.permanenties.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 8 more
```

The code in my HibernateUtil.java file is:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactoryBalie = new Configuration().configure("mysql_balie.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactoryBalie() {
    return sessionFactoryBalie;
}

}
```

The mysq_balie.cfg.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <!-- Development -->

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/balie?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=iso-8859-1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_catalog">db</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>-->

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="be/comp/model/balie/Zitdagen.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

I am unable to figure out where the error might be. All help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

you are missing jta.jar
with maven add this dep:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

or download from maven repository and add to your CLASSPATH

Comment: Gr8.. It was bug in 5.0.6.Final fixed in 5.0.7.Final

Answer (score 7):

Above answer is correct for Maven application. But in normal applications you just add a jar file called jta-1.1.jar.

-->If your using 3.x version, that is available under your downloading hibernate distribution jar's folder path called lib/required/jta-1.1.jar.

-->If your using hibernate 4.x version, that is available under distribution folder path called  dlist/lib/provided/jta-1.1.jar

Comment: In Hibernate 4.3 it is found in the file `jboss-transaction-api_xxx.jar`

Comment: @Johanna where do you find this jar (jboss-transaction-api_xxx.jar) in Hibernate 5.1 ?

Or any other jar is replaced jboss-transaction-api_xxx.jar in 5.1 release?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Maven/Gradle, the easier way is to download whole bundle instead of jar file one by one.

Go http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ and download the latest library, extract the jar from the `required` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the file: "jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final" which is in the path: /lib/required. This is in the final 5.5.7 version of hibernate